# Copy constructors and const& versus the ARM ABI

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, arm64, pass-by-value, abi

I'm trying to understand and take advantage of the ARMv8 ABI when choosing between pass-by-value versus pass-by-const&. In particular I have a struct that's a "Homogeneous Floating-point Aggregate (HFA)" in ARM lingo. I'll paste in some results from godbolt using armv8-a clang 18.1.0 with -O compiler switch. (I see similar disassembly results on my mac using Xcode 15.)

```
struct Thing {
    const double x,y;
    Thing( double a, double b) : x(a), y(b){}
    Thing( const Thing& other) = default;
    // Thing( const Thing& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {}
};

double diff( Thing t) {
    return t.x - t.y;
}

double baz(double x, double y)
{
    Thing i = {x, 5.};
    return diff(i);
}
```

I'm going to compare the defaulted copy constructor to the one I typed in. As written above, I get:

```
diff(Thing):                          // @diff(Thing)
        fsub    d0, d0, d1
        ret
baz(double, double):                               // @baz(double, double)
        fmov    d1, #-5.00000000
        fadd    d0, d0, d1
        ret
```

That looks good. The interface to `diff(Thing)` was for the caller to stick the two doubles into the register pair (d0,d1) and return the answer in register d0. There's no memory accessed anywhere--no mucking with the `SP` or `LP`; no stack frame created anywhere; no need to have the argument ever live in memory. And `baz(double, double)` looks good too. Everything inlined--no `Thing` even came to life.

But when I switch to the other version of the copy constructor, I get this for `diff(Thing)`:

```
diff(Thing):                          // @diff(Thing)
        ldp     d0, d1, [x0]
        fsub    d0, d0, d1
        ret
```

Suddenly now the caller needs to place the `Thing` in memory someplace and pass a pointer to that memory in x0. Then `diff(Thing)` has to go fetch the pair of doubles from that memory location. Ouch.

The `diff(Thing)` signature didn't change, but suddenly the ABI is completely different! Is this drastic difference documented somewhere? Why isn't my hand-typed copy-constructor just as good as the defaulted one? I'm glad so much got inlined for `baz`, but I want to know what is the best practice that I can hang on my wall? For example, for structs like this do I want:

`bool operator==( const Thing& lhs, const Thing& rhs)`

or

`bool operator==( Thing lhs, Thing rhs)`

or

`(let the compiler make one)`

I would like an explanation of the drastic difference above and advice on value v. const& parameters.

Comment: The only difference between your handmade copy ctor vs the defaulted one is that yours prevents the class from being "trivially copyable" (compiler is no longer sure bitwise copy is ok for your struct, and no it's not willing to look into the constructor body to check that). I'd search the ABI document for "trivially copyable".

Comment: Myself, I don't care about assembler anymore -- I'm currently targeting three platforms: 64 bit Windows, 64 bit Linux/x86, and Linux/ARM (not sure, might be 32 bit). I generally pass by reference if it's not a scalar type -- and since I also try to keep simple functions in the headers, the compiler can inline it if it wants to anyway.

Comment: @ChristianStieber I too used to pass non-scalers by const& out of habit (mostly because it makes debugging nicer) but I now wonder if that is now "stale" advice for modern C++. Will it force data into memory even with inlining? I also target different platforms, I'm just using ARM assembly as a proxy to what optimizers can do.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, well my type was already not "trivially copyable". I left out the part where I define `Thing& operator=(const Thing& rhs)` because by default it is deleted because of the const data members. I want my type to be immutable, but still have variables of the type have whole new values assigned to them. Oh, and that assignment operator didn't prevent the nice pass-in-registers behavior.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I checked is_trivially_copyable_v. My copy assignment breaks it. But it doesn't break the pass my struct in registers behavior.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread your comment.